# PCB layout, any improvements to make on the routing?

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, kicad, routing

I have designed the PCB below and would like some advice on good practice for my PCB routing / board schematic. Are there any design considerations that I should be paying attention to for the design?

This is a power switching board that is designed to handle 30 VDC @ 5 A. It uses transistors for switching, and comparators for measuring the voltage difference between two batteries. I've used thick traces, but I'm slightly concerned that their close proximity to each other may induce interference.

Please let me know if there's any other information needed and I can provide it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A ground plane is one of those good practices = you can skip that part of the routing. There's more reading from other questions here at EE, like this one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539064/pcb-power-trace-routing-problem

Comment: You have big traces that switch layers with a single via.  You can look up via current capacities given the dimensions but they also add inductance which might be a problem depending on the frequencies involved. I suggest either adding more vias or rerouting to make them unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe.. My feeling is that before even thinking about routing, your placing looks not good. Good placing for a switcher means that it is much tighter and that you need hardly any long traces. Then again before even thinking about placing, one would need a good schematic. This is not one for me. It looks straight away incomprehensible to me. So I suggest you begin with making a good schematic, then understand placing. Routing is the easiest part of these three things to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the insights everyone, I have a lot to think about. Are the inductances of vias a consideration here since i'm working with DC power sources? And for trace length, how long is too long? (what kind of considerations am i making when determining allowable trace length?) For reference the board is ~127x87mm.

Comment: @makotoyuki a ground plane is what you should concentrate on fixing first. Fix that then show the new layout. With GPs, track length becomes nearly irrelevant to induction problems <-- I think you haven't grasped this yet have you?

Comment: I think the problem might lie deeper. You seem to be using thick traces and large transistors or linear regulators (what I guess ld1086 are) to handle the output of your comparators lm393. But these can only source a couple milliampere. So, something's wrong conceptionally here.

Comment: Q3 doesn't seem to make sense at all. The gate voltage is at most one Schottky diode forward voltage above source voltage, so no matter what happens, Q3 is always off.

Comment: R1,R2,Q2 also seem senseless. Even assuming you would be changing the base of Q2, you'd only be pulling the gate of Q1 from its drain potential to still-pretty-close-to-drain potential. You usually don't want to operate a power MOSFET in linear region, so that seems wrong, as well.

Comment: There's more fundamental dysfunctionality, but at this point, you really just need to start from the beginning, and redo everything from scratch

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for taking the time to look at the circuit. Yes the regulators are outputting at the mA range, and it is meant to be received by a raspberry pi gpio, which can supply 16mA current per pin.

I'm not sure what you mean regarding Q3. I am using a voltage divider to properly bias the gate voltage to above Vgs(th) so that it can drain current from the Q2 base.

Comment: It's correct that w/ Q2's base at ~0A, there will only be a small drop in the Q1 Vgs. The idea is to have the drop (and therefore the value of R2) correspond to the Vgs(th) of Q1, so that Q1 does not conduct when Vext is connected, and does when Vext is removed.

Comment: @makotoyuki the regulators cannot be outputting in the milliampere range. Where would that high amount of  current come from?

Comment: Re: Q3: I already explained. Look at the Schottky diode connected to your "voltage divider": it limits the input voltage to GND + forward voltage of that Schottky diode, which is very low (~0.2 V, maybe)

Comment: Re:Re: Q3: You're right I see it! Sorry I wired the schematic incorrectly, the Vext signal should go to the main power line and then current will flow through the capacitor to GND. I will send a new, cleaner schematic.

As for the regulator, yes that is my mistake the regulators do not output current, it only regulates incoming voltage. In my case it will regulate a 20+V signal to a 3.3V signal. When fed to the gpio pins, it will be read as a HIGH. There is minimal current draw. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what this circuit is supposed to do. I know that inputs go on the left and outputs go on the right, so for the transistor part of the circuit, I see that Vext1 is the only input, and that part of the circuit produces Jint1, Jint2, and Load1 as outputs. If I assume that everything starts at ground potential and then some current is injected into Vext1, then the result is that Load1 gets powered, Q1 conducts a bit, and I don't see anything else interesting that will happen. I don't know what any of those transistors are for.

Comment: Sure, here's how its supposed to work.

When Vext is disconnected, Vint1/2's current flow to Q2 base, which provides a current path for the R1/R2 voltage divider to ground. R1/R2 bias the Q1 pmos to have a strong -Vgs (more negative than Vgsth), allowing current to flow to load. So Vint1/2 provide load voltage. 

When Vext is connected, R4/R5 bias the Q3 gate, redirecting current to GND. So Q2 no longer conducts and the current in R1/R2 doesn't have a ground path. The Vgs is now ~0V. Because it is now less negative than Vgsth, Q1 doesn't conduct. So Vext provides load voltage.

Comment: @makotoyuki you're still mistaken. These regulators *cannot* regulate without drawing a non-negligible amount of current. And you seem to *still* not have checked the LM393 datasheet to see that the LM393 can source extremely little current in high output. This schematic doesn't need to be cleaner, it needs to be ignored and re-done from scratch, while reading the datasheet of every single component very closely!

Comment: @makotoyuki you (in a questionable way, I don't think the schematic makes much sense now) solving the issue of Q3's gate being clamped to the wrong voltages still doesn't solve the R1,R2,Q2. Still makes no sense, even if you claim it makes.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marcus, I see the issue with the incompatible currents now. For the R1/R2 issue, it’s strange because I simulated the main circuit in spice and prototyped it in person (slightly different components) and it works fine, hence why I’m this far along in the process. But yes these issues warrant an extensive look over. I’ll see what I can do.

Comment: Source and drain of Q1 are swapped, all pads of Q1 should be used for heat spreading, LM393 has open collector outputs, so U5 - U8 never receive a signal. Common mode input voltage range of LM393 is violated, input above supply. P1 and P2 need a resistor to GND to define a voltage if nothing is plugged in.

Comment: ^To Marcus. Hello Marcus, I checked the circuit simulation again and rebuilt and tested the circuit. The Q1 gate voltage is not pulled to close to drain potential as you say. Lets say Vext = 30V, Jint1/2 = 25V. When Vext is removed, R1 and R2 bias the gate voltage to -6V, past the -2V Vgs threshold of Q1. So Jint1/2 established current to load. Now, when Vext is attached, VR1 = VR2, since current path to ground is interrupted by Q2. So gate voltage is the same as source potential, Vgs = ~0V, and Q1 does not conduct. Vext conducts current to load. Note Q1 is a PMOS, not a NMOS.

Comment: I think I see your point of confusion. Q1 has its D and S backwards in the schematic! I apologize for the mistake, I will pay more attention to these details next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A common ground plane is always recommended.
- Use copper pour to make the ground plane available everywhere
  possible
- use a trace width calculator to ensure that the traces can carry the
  required current. (this software is a good free offline calculator
  for various PCB-related calculations :
  https://saturnpcb.com/saturn-pcb-toolkit/)
- Triplet routing will be helpful for close-proximity routing of traces
  (https://www.edn.com/design-pcbs-for-emi-part-3-partitioning-and-routing/)
- A minimum of 0.25mm PCB edge clearance is needed for manufacturing.
  check with your manufacturer.

If you have specific questions, put them in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell what I know:

- calculate trace width, use more with some margin and excess for power ones
  ** switching nodes need thicker traces to avoid parasitic inductance and elements must be close to avoid parasitics
- Important is to use the rule of thumb for the gap between HV traces, not sure about the value and I will not post it for safety reasons and responsibility concern
- watch for parasitic capacitances too (i feel this is less important in most cases)

In other words, when you design layout you should focus on parasitics and responsibility, safety

Divided in groups, I get:
responsibility:

- the gap between HV traces
- the trace width

  parasitics:
- trace inductance
- capacitance between traces
- differential pairs for diff signals
- impedance matched and terminated transmission lines for cables
- use polygon unless application needs to not use
  I dont know if i know everything but at least this is a good starting point for beginner, I succeeded to make some good boards using these.
  One of them was a complex system with HV and different communications and linux system on module and all worked. I had issues only with the ethernet but it wasnt the layout.

When you have IC for example, you can use a short thin  trace from a pin to longer thick trace, this is common practice

Recently I found a good article about this, you can search for example "boost converter layout"
There are many good pdfs from manufacturers there

They are many things in layout design, I cant remember everything at the moment and missed some.

Sometimes good to use vias, some times bad
Your learn flow will tell you piece by piece, I told you the basics of safety first and performance sweetness